# MVC4 Unhandled Exception: Microsoft JScript runtime error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, runtime-error, jscript

I have an application MVC4 which I just started. I run the solution and get an error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error "The object doesn't accept this property or method"
```

My Index.cshtml file

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Menu Principal";
}

<h2>Home</h2>
```

My _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

I tagged in "razor" because all links I have seen talk about razor sections.
I have taken a look into the following links which proved to help others with similar problems, but could not make it work for me:

1. [ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts and Sections with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)
2. [MVC 4 and Jquery tricks](http://www.myfriedmind.com/2012/12/mvc-4-and-jquery-tricks-unhandled-exception-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-object-expected-0x800a138f-with-jquery/)

I already tried:

- Placing the "@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")" sentence before closing the head tag
- Placing the RenderBody before the RenderSection
- Removing the RenderSection (although this shouldn't be the problem, because debugging I've seen it crashes in the RenderBody sentence)

The exact line in which it crashes, within the jquery-2.0.0.js file, is in the following one:

```
window.addEventListener( "load", completed, false );
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery 2.0 on IE < 9, which it does not support.

Upgrade IE or downgrade jQuery.

Comment: incredible, all day fighting with this and it turned out to be something so simple. Thank you!